# How to add random values into an empty vector repeatedly without knowing when it would stop? How to count average number of steps?

Tags: matlab, random, montecarlo

Imagine the process of forming a vector `v` by starting with the empty vector and then repeatedly putting a randomly chosen number from 1 to 20 on the end of `v`. How could you use Matlab to investigate on average how many steps it takes before `v` contains all numbers from 1 to 20? You can define/use as many functions or scripts as you want in your answer.

```
v=[];
v=zeros(1,20);

for a = 1:length(v)
  v(a)=randi(20);
end
```

since `v` is now only a 1x20 vector, if there are two numbers equal, it definitely 
does not have all 20 numbers from 1 to 20

```
for i = 1:length(v)
  for j = i+1:length(v)
    if v(i)==v(j) 
      v=[v randi(20)];
      i=i+1;
      break;
    end
  end
end



for k = 1:length(v)
  for n = 1:20
    if v(k)==n
      v=v;
    elseif v(k)~=n
      a=randi(20);
      v=[v a];
    end
    if a~=n
      v=[v randi(20)];
      k=k+1;
      break;
    end
  end
end

disp('number of steps: ')
i*k
```

Comment: The following question on stats.stackexchange contains a Matlab simulation to ask how many times you need to roll a 6-sided die to get all numbers from 1-6 at least once: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48396/how-often-do-you-have-to-roll-a-6-sided-die-to-obtain-every-number-at-least-once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but maybe have a look at the `unique()` function.

if

```
length(unique(v)) == 20
```

then you have all values from 1:20 in your vector

```
v = []
counter = 0;
while length(unique(v)) ~= 20
    a = randi(20);
    v=[v a];
    counter = counter +1
end
```

the value `counter` should give you the number of iterations needed until v contains all values.

If you want to get the average amount of iterations by trial and error just make a look around this code and test it 10000 times and average the results form `counter`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! This works perfectly!! I hope this is what they are asking

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the loop generating the vector must be infinite. You can break out of the loop if your condition is met. This is how you can count how many steps you need. You cannot use a loop over 20 steps if you know you'll need more than that. I like using `while true` and `break`.

Next, your method of determining if all elements are present is a method of O(n<sup>2</sup>). This can be done in O(n log n) sorting the elements. This is what `unique` does. It works by sorting, which, in the general case, is O(n log n) (think QuickSort). So, drawing `n` elements and after each checking to see if you've got them all is an operation O(n<sup>2</sup> log n). This is expensive!

But we're talking about a finite set of integers here. Integers can be sorted in O(n) (look up histogram sort or radix sort). But we can do even better, because we don't even need to physically create the vector or sort its values. We can instead simply keep track of the elements we have seen in an array of length 20: In the loop, generate the next vector element, set the corresponding value in your 20-element array, and when all elements of this array are set, you have seen all values at least once. This is when you break.

My implementation of these two methods is below. The `unique` method takes 11s to do 10,000 repetitions of this process, and the other one only 0.37s. After 10,000 repetitions, I saw that you need about 72 steps on average to see all 20 integers.

```
function test

k = 10000;

tic;
n1 = 0;
for ii=1:k
   n1 = n1 + method1;
end
n1 = n1 / k;
toc
disp(n1)

tic;
n2 = 0;
for ii=1:k
   n2 = n2 + method2;
end
n2 = n2 / k;
toc
disp(n2)

end

function n = method1
k = 20;
v = [];
n = 1;
while true
   v(end+1) = randi(k);
   if numel(unique(v))==k
      break;
   end
   n = n + 1;
end
end

function n = method2
k = 20;
h = zeros(20,1);
n = 1;
while true
   h(randi(k)) = 1;
   if all(h)
      break;
   end
   n = n + 1;
end
end
```

Note on the timings: I use `tic`/`toc` here, but it is usually better to use `timeit` instead. The time difference is large enough for this to not matter all that much. But do make sure that the code that uses `tic`/`toc` is inside a function, and not copy-pasted to the command line. Timings are not representative when using `tic`/`toc` on the command line because the JIT compiler will not be used.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am just a beginner in matlab.. I'm still figuring out where to put my 'break'..I'll learn your second method!